# Center this text inside this special image slider

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to get the text inside these images.

The overview of the problem -> I basically need to have text inside each image.

Link to codepen --> https://codepen.io/martispyc/pen/KKmjWZj?editors=1100

Appreciated if the slider would slide these kinds of divs, not the images and text, but whatever works!

```
    <div class="slider__images--container">
        <img src="" alt="" class="slider__images--container-img">
        <h3 class="slider__images--container-h3">Example</h3>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, for everyone wondering, I solved it myself! I did put text inside and I am proud of it. The basic way I did it was as follows:

1. I added the same amount of text blocks as my slider has images. After that,
2. I coded some javascript so the nth text block as the nth image has the class .active

2.5 text had absolute positioning so I can move it around and `a z-index of >1

3. .active == opacity 1, .unactive == opacity 0.
4. And then I made it so every time it slides it checks which one has to be active (text block) and add the class and remove active from the last one.
5. Added a transition and boom!

(Basic rundown of how I did it, won't share the code only because of the thrill coding it up yourself!) byebye!

PS. I won't accept my answer just so if there's someone willing to put a real answer, go for it!